# ¿Desde dónde llamar a System.out.println considerando buenas prácticas?

Tags: java

Tengo una duda con lo que al `System.out.println` se refiere.

Utilizo `System.out.println` para indicar qué data introducir por medio de los `Scanner` o para notificar al usuario qué ha sucedido.

No sé si utilizar `System.out.println`

- en la clase main, o
- en la clase que contiene los métodos para las funcionalidades de mi programa.

Desde el punto de vista de mejores prácticas y legibilidad del código, ¿desde dónde debería llamarlo para imprimir en pantalla?

Comment: @lois6b No es recomendable traducirlas nosotros ya que si el usuario no habla español tendremos una pregunta que no le servirá de nada al usuario. Lo mejor es esperar a que el propio usuario que lo ha publicado lo traduzca o bien si se ha equivocado se migra a stackoverflow en inglés :).

Answer (score 1):

Mi opinión es que hay que intentar que las diferentes capas de datos se mantengan independientes entre sí.

La función que comentas sirve para volcar mensajes a la salida estándar... bien, estas salidas no deberían producirse por defecto ni en la capa de acceso a datos ni tampoco en la lógica de negocio (salvo para tareas de depuración). Lo ideal es que esta función fuese llamada únicamente desde la capa de presentación o frontend.

¿Por qué? Veámoslo desde otra perspectiva más sencilla de entender.

Imagina una aplicación que se comunica con una base de datos. Al tener que interactuar con la base de datos en ocasiones lo más cómodo será pensar...

> ah vale, pues meto la consulta directamente en mi código porque total, esta consulta no se va a necesitar en otras partes

Bien, al final resulta que acabas con una aplicación en el que las consultas a la base de datos se encuentran repartidas por todo el sistema. Acaba pareciendo una infección que se ha repartido por todo el proyecto.

¿Cuánto costaría ahora cambiar de base de datos? ¿O de modificar ciertas tablas? Si de repente tienes que añadir transacciones y gestión de errores... ¿Vas a ser algo trivial y sencillo de implantar?

Comment: +1, pero sugiero la edición: Cambiar **Mi opinión** por quiza: **La idea general**, **La mayoria de desarrolladores**, **Lo recomendable**

Comment: @jasilva he visto tantas cosas programando (supongo que como cualquiera) que no me queda tan claro que la mayoría de desarrolladores respalde mi postura :)

Comment: Creo que los *buenos* programadores respaldarian tu postura

Answer (score -1):

En una aplicación real, es más elegante (y tiene más sentido) utilizar *logging* (utilizando algún frame [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/index.html) por ejemplo). Para los propósitos de estudio como es el tuyo actualmente, en realidad es un poco indiferente. Puedes (y debes) proporcionar toda la información posible que sea útil para poder hacer *debugging* del programa o para informar al usuario. Para ese propósito, cualquier lugar donde se cumpla será adecuado para utilizar System.out.println()

Comment: Lo que indicas luce bien para un debug pero OP indica que la interacción con el usuario es mediante la consola.

Answer (score -1):

Lo correcto es utilizar el `System.out.println` en el método `main`, nunca deberías usarlo dentro de un método de una clase como por ejemplo en la clase en la que usas los métodos del ArrayList. Lo mejor es que lo que quieras mostrar lo metas en un método que devuelva el String con lo que quieres mostrar, por ejemplo:

```
public class Universidad {

    private List<Estudiante> estudiantes;

    public Universidad(ArrayList<Estudiante> estudiantes) {
        this.estudiantes = estudiantes;
    }

    public String getNumeroEstudiantes() {
        return "El número de estudiantes es de " + estudiantes.size();
    }

}
```

Y luego en el `main`:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Universidad universidad = new Universidad(Arrays.asList("Pepe", "Juan");
        System.out.println(universidad.getNumeroEstudiantes());
    }
}
```

Esto mostrará por pantalla:

`El número de estudiantes es 2`

Answer (score -2):

Mira, los System.out.println() en general los puedes utilizar tanto en los métodos como en el método Main. Pero por convención, todo lo que sea System.out.println() es mejor dejarlo en el método Main. Si quieres debuguear tu programa, puedes ponerlos dentro de los métodos en donde estás haciendo las operaciones, pero luego es mejor sacarlos.

Comment: No he votado en contra, pero no creo que solo deba llamarse en el método `main`. Tal parece que tus clases solo cubren un pequeño tópico, y yo extendería la recomendación a que se realice esta llamada a los métodos que se asocien con la presentación de tu sistema para la interacción humano-computadora.

Answer (score -2):

La salida de datos en *Java*, es sencilla pues basta con usar `System.out.println`, mostrando datos por pantalla en nuestros programas, puede usarse tanto en la clase `main` como en las otras clases.

```
String valor = "";
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
valor = reader.nextLine();
System.out.println("Valor ingresado en pantalla : " + valor);
```

> En la clase main, o en la clase que contiene los métodos para las funcionalidades de mi programa.

No afectará la funcionalidad del programa si solo nos enfocamos a esta línea de código, y siempre será legible. Siempre que esté dentro del `main`, puedes llamarlo desde cualquier método de tu programa.

```
System.out.println(
    "Aprendiendo a comentar" + "\n"
    "en StackOverflow." + "\n"
    "Saludos."
);
```